# Granting access to only specific azure storage container

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload data to azure blob storage under a specific container (suppose container "test1"). But access key(connection string) grant the access to other available containers( conatiner "test2", "test3") too.

Is there any other authorisation mechanism that allow access to only single container "test1" ?

Note : Using spring-boot application for file upload as blob, where access key(connection string) goes in environment file.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other authorisation mechanism that allow access to only
> single container "test1" ?

Yes. Simplest would be to create a Shared Access Signature (SAS) token for "test1" blob container. You will only be able to perform operations on this blob container only.

To learn more about Shared Access Signature, please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview.